# Is running Whonix with a Windows 10 Host a bad idea?

Tags: tails, ip-address, whonix, ip-address-leak, malware

I'm considering using either a Tails stick on my spare laptop or Whonix on my PC via Virtualbox. Only problem is, said PC is a Windows 10 system.

Is it more secure to just go with the Tails plan, or can I virtually gaurantee the Host has no idea of any activity inside the VM(s)?

I'm particularly worried about I.P leakage (through driveby attacks probably), which is why I'm currently looking into Whonix, but I'm new(ish) to this whole thing, so advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It depends _entirely_ on your threat model... Whonix makes it harder to leak your IP than Tails, but Whonix in a VM also depends on your host OS being trustworthy.

Comment: https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Host_Operating_System_Selection#Windows_Hosts